# Am using Chart.js and am trying to list the attendances for the last 7 days

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, chart.js

```
List<int> repartitions = new List<int>();
var membs = students.Select(p => p.MembershipID).Distinct();
var attend = students.Select(p => p.Attendances.Select(o => o.AttendanceID).Distinct());

DateTime[] Last7days = Enumerable.Range(0, 7).Select(i => DateTime.Now.AddDays(-i)).ToArray();
foreach (var day in Last7days) {
  foreach (var item in attend) {
    repartitions.Add(students.Count(x=>x.Attendances.Any().Equals(item)));
    //repartitions.Add(students.Count(x => x.MembershipID == item));
  }
}
```

Am trying to show the amount of times a student attended in the last 7 days but i am getting the following exception

> Cannot compare elements of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[[System.Int32,`

Answer (score 0):

You might be comparing Int value with some kind of object. Your `item` variable contains `AttendanceID` only and you are comparing this value to `student` object.

You may need to change your condition like this

```
repartitions.Add(students.Count(x=>x.Attendances.Select(o => o.AttendanceID.Equals(item)));
```

Comment: I tried this before but i got the following error `cannot implicitly convert Ennumberable<bool> to bool`